# Eclipse IDE - C# plugin that supports Microsoft .NET Framework

Tags: c#, eclipse, plugins, ide

Is there a plugin for Eclipse that allows you to write C# code using the **.Net Framework** and not Mono?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Emonic](http://emonic.sourceforge.net).
See the [FAQ](http://emonic.sourceforge.net/html/FAQ.html):

> #### Which .NET implementations can I use?
>
> Microsoft's implementation as well as Mono :-) Emonic supports .net 1.* as well as .net 2.* and 3.*.
>
> #### Which compiler is used to compile the sources?
>
> Emonic does not use a compiler directly. The build mechanism writes creates a build file and invokes a build command on that build file. Thus, the compiler used is the compiler which is configured in the build's setup. At the moment, Apache Ant and NAnt is supported as a build mechanism. In the case of NAnt, you can choose the compiler via a command line flag. You can write this flag in the Emonic preferences of the nant-start to force emonic to use this compiler.